# conda--can't install, uninstall, or change anything in base environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Any time I try to install, uninstall, or update any package in my base conda environment, the solver runs forever until eventually giving me an "incompatible packages" error. I've tried running `conda update --all` and reverting back to previous configurations but I run into the same issue. Short of uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling from scratch, is there anything that can be done? If I have to reset the base environment to factory defaults, I'd be okay with that but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04, conda version is 4.10.3 with python 3.8.

Comment: Same kind of probleme for me, conda runs for hours/days then fails when checking dependancies. I uninstalled /reinstalled anaconda. Same problem again. is there a clean solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll share my solution in case it helps anyone in the same situation. It was part user error on my part. The official Anaconda installation, which I was using at the time, comes with a package named Anaconda which is really just a wrapper for the collection of scientific tools that comes pre-installed. Anyway, this "package" is only available through the official Anaconda channel so when I modified the configuration to use conda-forge as the default channel instead, it somehow broke the solver.

**The fix:** Add `anaconda` back to the top of the channel config

```
> conda config --add channels anaconda
```

Now, you can remove the `anaconda` package

```
> conda uninstall anaconda
```

If desired, you should now be able to safely modify your `.condarc` file and remove `anaconda` from the list of channels.